# Delphi SQL query

Tags: sql, delphi, datetime

I was wondering if you could take a look at my code for date comparison on Delphi.

Code snippet in DELPHI:-

```
        // SQL QUERY to gather member information.
           DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
           DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select HPFROMDT, HPthruDt, MEMBERKEY, MEMBHPKEY, OPFROMDT, OPTHRUDT, HPCODEKEY' +
                                 ' from MEMBHP' +
                                 ' where MEMBERKEY = ''' + MembKey + '''   and OPFROMDT <= ''' + date_request + ''' and OPTHRUDT > ''' + date_request +''' '
```

Script snippet in SQL:-

```
SELECT [MEMBHPKEY]
      ,[MEMBERKEY]
      ,[CURRHIST]
      ,[HPFROMDT]
      ,[OPFROMDT]
      ,[OPTHRUDT]
      ,[HPCODEKEY]
      ,[HPOPTIONKEY]

  FROM [main].[dbo].[*****]

  where MEMBERKEY = '1234567' and OPFROMDT <= '2007-08-01' and OPTHRUDT > '2007-08-01'
```

The SQL script obviously compares a constant date  value with the extracted date values. And it works!

However, the Delphi code doesn’t work. The error message

> *Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime
>   date type.*

I believe there has to be some kind of conversion technique for Delphi that should allow me to convert into the right variable type…. Any ideas?

I extract `date_request` as a string variable from a text file....

```
  for i := 11 to length(buffer) do
                        begin
                             DT_request := DT_request + buffer[i];
                        end;
```

Comment: It's really hard to answer this when you show the Delphi version using ` + date_request + `, but you don't show us what you put in `date_request`.

Comment: I extract date_request as a string variable from a text file. 

                        'for i := 11 to length(buffer) do
                        begin
                             DT_request := DT_request + buffer[i];
                        end;'

Comment: See my answer below. I've addressed that as well.

Comment: You still don't show the contents of that variable.  If you inspect the contents of DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL after you set it, you will see that it probably does not match the SQL text in the second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extraction process was picking up a garbage '*' value at the end of the date. This was the problem during date comparison in SQl.

I used

```
Showmessage(DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL[0]);
```

and it showed me that the date_request was actually resulting into a '20070815*'... Once I figured that out, it was an easy fix. Remove the '*' and compare just as I did previously.

```
// SQL QUERY to gather member information.
DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select HPFROMDT, HPthruDt, MEMBERKEY, MEMBHPKEY, OPFROMDT, OPTHRUDT, HPCODEKEY' +
                       ' from MEMBHP' +
                       ' where MEMBERKEY = ''' + MembKey + '''   and OPFROMDT <= ''' + date_request + ''' and OPTHRUDT > ''' + date_request +''' '
```

Comment: I'm glad you figured out the problem, but you really should have done that *before* you posted your question. Looking at the generated SQL should have been among your first debugging steps, not necessarily to check that the SQL was valid, but to see whether the *same* SQL behaved the same way when you ran it manually as when you did programmatically. However, if you're going to post the "correct" SQL here in your answer, please take care to proofread your answer to make sure it's complete, and then edit your answer to fix any mistakes you find.

Comment: Hey Rob, I posted the question while I was going through the debugging steps. those who took the time to answer my questions, I am thankful to. I appreciate their time. I don't see anything wrong with asking for help and simultaneously debugging my code.

Answer (score 4):

Use dates (`TDateTime` values) to represent dates, and use parameterized queries to let the database driver convert them to the proper  format.

```
// New code snippet from Delphi:
DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select HPFROMDT, HPthruDt, MEMBERKEY, MEMBHPKEY, OPFROMDT, OPTHRUDT, HPCODEKEY');
DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('from MEMBHP where MEMBERKEY = :MembKey and OPFROMDT <= :date_request and');
DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('and OPTHRUDT > :date_request');
DMS.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('MembKey'.AsString := MembKey;
DMS.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('date_request').AsDateTime := ARealDateTimeValue;
DMS.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('date_request') := ARealDateTimeValue;
```

If you are getting the string from a text file, you have to make sure it's the right format for your database first. According to your information, that would be in the `CCYY-MM-DD` format. You can then use `AsString` instead of `AsDateTime` to assign the values to the parameters.

Comment: TADOQuery doesnt contain a parameter named ParamByName

Comment: See my edit. (It seems that with a little effort you could have figured that out yourself, though.)

Comment: I tried doing the same however it didnt work. The issue was something different. The extraction process was picking up a garbage '*' value at the end of the date. This was the problem during date comparison in SQl.

Comment: Using parameters means that a) you don't have to worry about getting all the embedded `'` characters right, and also makes sure you don't have bad data or SQL injection issues. It also allows the database engine to compile the SQL once, which makes things much faster if you're dealing with any volume of data at all.

Comment: yeah i had bad data. i posted how i fixed it. thanks, something triggered in my mind that I had bad data. .... 
"You still don't show the contents of that variable."

Answer (score 1):

Use paramters ...

```
AdoQuery1.SQL.TExt:
Declare @Date smalldatetime
Select @Date=:Date
SELECT [MEMBHPKEY]
       ,[MEMBERKEY]
       ,[CURRHIST]  
       ,[HPFROMDT]
       ,[OPFROMDT]
       ,[OPTHRUDT]
       ,[HPCODEKEY]
       ,[HPOPTIONKEY] 
FROM [main].[dbo].[MEMBHP]
where MEMBERKEY =:memberkey and OPFROMDT <= @Date and OPTHRUDT > @Date

AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParseSQL(AdoQuery1.SQL.TExt,true);
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Date').DataType := ftDatetime;
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Date').Value := StrToDate('1.1.2012');
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('memberkey').Value := 123;
```

Comment: [DCC Error] EDI270_2271.pas(633): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Pointer'
[DCC Warning] EDI270_2271.pas(633): W1058 Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'ShortString'
[DCC Error] EDI270_2271.pas(633): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

Comment: also, I dont understand the first part of your comment:-

Declare @Date smalldatetime
Select @Date=:Date

I am extracting date_request as a string variable from a text file. and the code is in Delphi Pascal, not SQL.

Comment: I know .... mine was the SQL.ADD Part, Delphi Part would be
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParseSQL(AdoQuery1.SQL.TExt,true);
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Date').DataType := ftDatetime;
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Date').Value := StrToDate('1.1.2012');
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('memberkey').Value := 123;

Comment: This answer is incomplete without an explanation or demonstration of how to link the given SQL with the surrounding Delphi code. You need to show how the SQL is supposed to resolve the `:Date` and `:memberkey` expressions.